# Where to instantiate a client for an external service in Django?

Tags: python, django

What is the accepted practice in Django for creating an instance of a client for an external service (e.g. Zookeeper, Cassandra, Redis, etc.)?

I need this client to perform a "set key" operation from inside a view and I don't want to create the client on each request due to high overhead.

Currently I've declared it as a global variable in `views.py`, but that's not really ok, because it gets instantiated when I do `python manage.py makemigrations` too.

A really stripped down example of the issue:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from app.views import MyView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', MyView.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse
from kazoo.client import KazooClient
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

zk = KazooClient(hosts="127.0.0.1:2181")
zk.start()


# Create your views here.
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        value, _ = zk.get("/my_zk_key")
        return HttpResponse("value: {}".format(value))
```

The problem is that the zookeeper client gets created and connects in cases other than `runserver`, like this:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
INFO:kazoo.client:Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2181
DEBUG:kazoo.client:Sending request(xid=None): Connect(protocol_version=0, last_zxid_seen=0, time_out=10000, session_id=0, passwd=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', read_only=None)
INFO:kazoo.client:Zookeeper connection established, state: CONNECTED
No changes detected
$
```

I'm looking for an accepted practice in Django for dealing with such cases.

Comment: you can make the class which creates the connection as singleton

Comment: Please supply a little more information regarding how and where the client is currently created (your current code) in order to supply the best solution.  Different services/suppliers/clients might have different suggested solutions. (For example, Django creates singleton DB 
"connections" on launch, but the DB itself is only connected when a query is executed).

Comment: added a tiny example which shows the problem

Answer (score 0):

If your problem can be reduced to the last point, you can avoid setting your global variable during the migration with:

```
import sys
if 'makemigrations' not in sys.argv and 'migrate' not in sys.argv:
     # variable setting here
```

Comment: I'd rather not do this, it looks like a hack more than an accepted practice :(

Comment: You're certainly right, but it works! I did not find any other mean to know if the current process is a migration or not. I asked SO but got no answer.